# How to publish a scoped npm package to a private Bytesafe npm registry using an Auth Token

Tags: npm

I am trying to write my first npm package and test publishing to my private bytesafe npm registry using an AUTH TOKEN, before I go ahead and incorporate publishing from a CI pipeline.

I have logged in to my bytesafe directory and acquired a TOKEN:

```sh
npm --registry https://<<my.bytesafe.registry string goes here>> login with User: bytesafe Password: <passwd>
npm --registry https://<<my.bytesafe.registry string goes here>> token create Password: <passwd>
```

I have created my ~/.npmrc file as follows:

```sh
//<<my.bytesafe.registry string goes here>>/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
registry=https://<<my.bytesafe.registry string goes here>
email=<my email addess>
always-auth=true
```

My `package.json`:

```sh
{
  "name": "@spears/tryitandsee",
  "version": "1.0.1-0",
  ...
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://<my.bytesafe.registry string goes here>"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm publish` I am receiving the following error message:

```sh
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - PUT https://<my.bytesafe.regsitry string goes here>/@spears%2ftryitandsee - Access Denied
```

How do I publish to a private npm registry using an auth token?

Solved it! It was a typo issue!

Answer (score 1):

Publishing scoped packages to a private registry is supported so this is most likely related to an expired token.

Hopefully, you have already managed to solve your problem. If you are still having issues with your private registry, I would suggest that you contact the support at https://bytesafe.dev as we would be happy to help troubleshoot your issue.

/Martin,
Bytesafe Team